# What is exactly "This sounds like barn door statistics!"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> *This sounds like barn door statistics!*

What does [this phrase?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/44732/have-only-girls-been-born-for-a-long-time-in-this-village?noredirect=1#comment205154_44732) mean?

Comment: Barn door statistics ~ ball park figures?

Comment: A barn door is proverbially wide.

Comment: I propose statistics discussed in front of barn doors are more prone to errors than otherwise

Comment: Better context needed -- it makes me think of ''closing the barn door after the cows got out", though "barn door" is also used to mean a large surface.

Comment: There's also the phrase "Couldn't hit the broad side of a barn" indicating that someone is inaccurate

Comment: It's not a phrase I've seen before (except in the comment you're quoting: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/44732/have-only-girls-been-born-for-a-long-time-in-this-village ) but I read it as meaning *ex post facto* https://www.wordnik.com/words/ex%20post%20facto

Comment: It might be a reference to the Texas Sharpshooter Fallacy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_sharpshooter_fallacy

Comment: It was indeed a reference to the Texas Sharpshooter fallacy

Answer (score 2):

The answer from above wiki link is so much fun it must be worth entering here on the ELU site;

The name is from a joke about a shifty  Texan who shoots at a barn, then paints a target centered on the tightest cluster of hits, then claims to be a sharpshooter!

It refers the tendency of some , to infer trends in statistics where none exist.